# If $P(a\leq X\leq b)=1$ then $\mathrm{Var}(X)\leq(b-a)^2/4$

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable and suppose that
$$P(a\leq X\leq b)=1,$$
for some $-\infty<a<b<\infty$. How to show that
$$Var(X)\leq \frac{(b-a)^2}{4}?$$

This is an exercise in an introductory probability textbook in a chapter that introduces Chebychev's inequality
$$P(|X-\mu|\geq K\sigma)\leq\frac{1}{K^2}.$$
So I suspect there is a simple proof using this, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $a\leqslant X\leqslant b$ almost surely implies that $|X-\frac12(a+b)|\leqslant c$ almost surely, where $c=\tfrac12(b-a)$, hence $(X-\tfrac12(a+b))^2\leqslant c^2$ almost surely, in particular, $$\mathrm{Var}(X)=E((X-E(X))^2)=\min_{x\in\mathbb R}E((X-x)^2)\leqslant E((X-\tfrac12(a+b))^2)\leqslant c^2.$$ *Exercise:* Show that the upper bound on the RHS is optimal by exhibiting some $X$ with support in $[a,b]$ such that $\mathrm{Var}(X)=c^2$.

Answer (score 3):

$Var(X) \leq E\left(X-\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right)^2 \leq \dfrac{(b-a)^2}{4}$

The first inequality is because $EX = \arg\min_{c \in \mathbb{R}} E(X-c)^2$